# Summary statistics for variable, grouped by another variable

Tags: r, average, summary

I am looking to find the summary statistics (mean and potentially standard deviation and other quantities) of a vector (column) in a data frame, but grouped. I hope to group the statistics by another categorical variable

I know that one find summary as

```
summary(data$rating)
```

however I am not sure how I find summary statistics for gender separately.

I tried

```
summary(data$rating, data$gender)
```

but that does give my anything but `summary(data$rating)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `by` function:

```
by(data$rating, data$gender, summary)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `tapply()` or `aggregate()`:

```
data <- data.frame(rating = 100*runif(30), 
                   gender=sample(c("female","male"),30, replace=TRUE))

tapply(data$rating, data$gender, summary)

aggregate(data$rating, by=list(data$gender), 
      FUN=function(x) cbind(mean(x), median(x), sd(x)))
```